# Error: Call to a member function getCategoryId() on null when trying to get Category from \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, phtml, delivery-time

so I'm trying to check if the category ID is 6 to change the text that appears in delivery time, but when I try to call the `$_product`, it says that it's `null`, and I can't figure out why.

Any help would really be appreciated.

**delivery-time.phtml**:

```
<?php

/* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */

$_product = $block->getProduct();
$category = $_product->getCategoryId();
?>

<div class="delivery-time__wrapper">
    <span class="lb-icon-rocket"></span>
    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($category) ?></span>
    <?php if ($category && $category == 6): ?>
        <span class="delivery-time__text">
            <?= __("Delivery in 6-12 weeks"); ?>
        </span>
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="delivery-time__text">
            <?= __("Delivery in 2-3 business days"); ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

**Erro:**

```
Error: Call to a member function getCategoryId() on null
```

**Delivery Time Block:**

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.delivery.time" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/delivery-time.phtml"/>
```

**catalog_product_view.xml:**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <remove src="mage/gallery/gallery.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Tmg\Breadcrumbs\Block\Breadcrumbs"
                   name="breadcrumbs.mobile" as="breadcrumbs.mobile"
                   template="Magento_Theme::html/breadcrumbs.phtml"
                   before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <container name="product.top" htmlClass="pdp__top group" htmlTag="div" after="breadcrumbs.mobile"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.delivery.time" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/delivery-time.phtml"/>

            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell" name="catalog.product.crosssell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

            <block class="Tmg\Breadcrumbs\Block\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" template="Magento_Theme::html/breadcrumbs.phtml" before="-" />

            <block name="product.info.sizeguide" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/sizeguide.phtml"/>

            <block name="product.info.color" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/color-info.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

**File directory layout:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below code in your **delivery-time.phtml** file:

```
Replace the below code in your **delivery-time.phtml** file:

<?php

/* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */

$_product = $block->getProduct();

?>

<div class="delivery-time__wrapper">
    <span class="lb-icon-rocket"></span>
    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($category) ?></span>
    <?php if (in_array("6",$product->getCategoryIds())): ?>
        <span class="delivery-time__text">
            <?= __("Delivery in 6-12 weeks"); ?>
        </span>
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="delivery-time__text">
            <?= __("Delivery in 2-3 business days"); ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Same error. Here is a full log: https://pastebin.com/SvTpp4tC

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: @DeadSec code updated... please try again with updated code.